# Kendo UI Grid set Page / goto Page (JSP)

Tags: jquery, jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have a Problem with kendo grid and seting up inital Page.

Initial situation:

I have a Grid with many entries, one of them is the right one. On wich Page this entry is i dont know.

What i have tried:

in the databound event i identify the Item(Object) on which page it is (loop over the datasource). after this i want to set the initial page, but if i use dataSource.page(index) javscript shows error -> "too much recursion".

Where to set the initial Page?

I'm using JSP and Jquery

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution :**

```
dataBound: function() {
 var newPageIndex = calculatePageIndex();

 if ( newPageIndex != this.dataSource.page() ) {
      this.dataSource.page(newPageIndex);
 }}
```

**If you bind databound to a js Function:**

```
<kendo:grid name="grid" dataBound="bound" > 
</kendo:grid>


function bound(e){
    //find on which page the item/object is
    var index = calculatePageIndex();
    if ( index != e.sender.dataSource.page() ) {
      e.sender.dataSource.page(index);
    }
}
```